# understand different UDP packet loss results: iperf3 vs nuttcp

Tags: udp, packet

I try to measure UDP [%packet loss] between two machines.
I'm getting different results while using two different tools:

1. iperf3:

```
machine 1: iperf3 -s 
machine 2: iperf3 -c <machine_1_ip> -u -b0
```

result:

```
[  5] local 172.25.12.25 port 5201 connected to 172.25.12.9 port 46605
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  31.2 MBytes   261 Mbits/sec  0.113 ms  566/4557 (12%)  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.113 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.113 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.113 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  4.69 MBytes  39.4 Mbits/sec  0.162 ms  65056/65656 (99%)  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.162 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.162 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.162 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.162 ms  0/0 (0%)  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  6.20 MBytes  52.1 Mbits/sec  0.139 ms  64856/65650 (99%)  
[  5]  10.00-10.25  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.139 ms  0/0 (0%)  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-10.25  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  0.139 ms  130478/135863 (96%)
```

2. nuttcp:

machine 1: nuttcp -S
machine 2: nuttcp -u -i -Ri50000m <machine_1_ip>

```
    result:

    83.5605 MB /   1.00 sec =  700.9434 Mbps  1581 / 87147 ~drop/pkt  1.81 ~%loss
      102.1035 MB /   1.00 sec =  856.5107 Mbps  4434 / 108988 ~drop/pkt  4.07 ~%loss
      108.7383 MB /   1.00 sec =  912.1637 Mbps  1651 / 112999 ~drop/pkt  1.46 ~%loss
      109.0381 MB /   1.00 sec =  914.6668 Mbps  1863 / 113518 ~drop/pkt  1.64 ~%loss
      108.7529 MB /   1.00 sec =  912.2939 Mbps  1534 / 112897 ~drop/pkt  1.36 ~%loss
      109.3838 MB /   1.00 sec =  917.5759 Mbps  1515 / 113524 ~drop/pkt  1.33 ~%loss
      107.4248 MB /   1.00 sec =  901.1491 Mbps  1337 / 111340 ~drop/pkt  1.20 ~%loss
      108.1553 MB /   1.00 sec =  907.2559 Mbps  1620 / 112371 ~drop/pkt  1.44 ~%loss
      110.3291 MB /   1.00 sec =  925.5187 Mbps   722 / 113699 ~drop/pkt  0.64 ~%loss
```

I get similar bandwidth but different lost percentage.
What can I do now? maybe try a third tool?

Comment: `iperf` seems to overload something, so you have nearly 99% loss after several seconds where it doesn't send anything? Maybe it's sending packets faster, and this is breaking something? `nuttcp` gets a sustained drop rate. You could debug this with `wireshark` to see the timing of the packets.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Are you familiar with a way to increase the udp packets buffers or reduce the send speed rate while using iperf3?  (maybe I'll notice some improvements)

Comment: Try using a specific target bandwidth with `-b` instead of unlimited bandwith.